# Parsing error when adding 'integrity' attribute on script tags

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a 'crypto-js' library and adding the 'integrity' attribute to a Stripe CDN using this way

```
import { SHA256 } from 'crypto-js';

const StripeInit = () => {
  const stripeScript = document.createElement('script');
  stripeScript.defer = true;
  const hashingStripe = SHA256('https://js.stripe.com/v3').toString();
  stripeScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://js.stripe.com/v3/');
  stripeScript.setAttribute('integrity', hashingStripe);
  stripeScript.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous');
  document.head.appendChild(stripeScript);
};

export default StripeInit;
```

But I get the following error

> Error parsing 'integrity' attribute ('b178f591ba38eb1c0c72447cd31ff08740553dee8beaba61d8f59466b79ae0a7'). The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character.

If I try to concatenate the (string) hash value with 'sha256-' or 'sha512-' as mentioned in the above error, the script gets blocked.

I was trying to add an 'integrity' attribute to script tags to ensure the external scripts are from a trusted source.

Comment: Doesn't `SHA256()` already return a string? Why can't you simply add `-` to the end?

Answer (score 1):

You need to yse SHA-256 hash of the *content* of the file at `https://js.stripe.com/v3`, not the URL itself.

Also bear-in-mind, the point of Subresource Integrity is to validate that the content of the file is unmodified. If a bad actor got control of the CDN that serves the file and adds malicious code to the file, the integrity check would not validate and the file would not be downloaded.

With this in mind, if we were to dynamically download the script and generate a SHA-256 from that at runtime (which I assume you are trying to do here), we would already have downloaded the malicious version of the file and thus it makes the integrity check moot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to calculate the hash at runtime. It has to be hardcoded in your code and it is based on the pre-calculated hash of the script's content.

If you don't want to manually calculate the hash, you can use this website (https://www.srihash.org) to easily generate the code to include the script with the right integrity attribute.

In the case of `https://js.stripe.com/v3` the website returns this script:

```
<script
  src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"
  integrity="sha384-GQHY4Z83dMy7Ne72CxMt/gC1xQz7CN+yfjXeZ8kSGX2v3iPl2ym6Z94KqQ7qyf5S"
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```